# Can not have multiple default rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire, firebase-security

I am using GeoFire to store location in Firebase realtime database. I have 2 tables `table-a` and `table-b`. For both of these tables, I would like to enable indexing. On saving the below rules, Firebase prompts the following error:

Cannot have multiple default rules ('$table-a' and '$table-b').

```
    {
      "rules": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "auth != null",
          "$table-a": {
          ".indexOn":"g"
            },
          "$table-b": {
          ".indexOn":"g"
            }
      }
    }
```

Any ideas on what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should do as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "table-a": {
      ".indexOn":"g"
        },
      "table-b": {
      ".indexOn":"g"
        }
  }
}
```

As explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#location), the `$location` syntax is "used to reference the key of a `$location` that was used earlier in a rule structure"

Comment: Thank you. Here's another problem from the newbie. :) Maybe you have any idea?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646383/firebase-simulate-read-denied